# Why is Testcafe waiting for an elementl to appear when the element is already there?

Tags: angular, for-loop, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe 0.22.0 and in a `beforeEach`, I have this code:

```
const checkedBoxes = Selector('input[type="checkbox"]')

for (let i = 0; i < await checkedBoxes.count; i++) {
    t.click(Selector(`#product-${i} input`))
}
```

When I run in Chrome, the page almost immediately renders everything, but testcafe is still waiting about 5 seconds before it clicks any checkbox.  Whenever it clicks a checkbox, it waits 5 more seconds before it clicks the next checkbox.

Why is this happening?  It should be possible for testcafe to check all of these at once.

This is an angular 6 app.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to reproduce the issue with your test code and my sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="product-0">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div id="product-1">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div id="product-2">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div id="product-3">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div id="product-4">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

test code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `check`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;


test('basic', async t => {
    const checkedBoxes = Selector('input[type="checkbox"]');

    for (let i = 0; i < await checkedBoxes.count; i++) {
        await t.click(Selector(`#product-${i} input`));
    }
});
```

I do not see any delays in click actions. Besides, I've found that you missed `await` [keyword before](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/#performing-actions-on-the-page) the `t.click` action. If you still have issue could you please provide us with minimal sample example which demonstates the issue?